# create a dictionary in python from columns of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key-value

I have the below sample data:

```
class   name
Pref    Ab
Val     BE
Base    es
Pref    Cw
Base    SS
```

This data is in a dataframe and I need to create a mapping for class : name as shown below:

```
Pref : ['Ab','Cw'],
Val  : ['BE'],
Base : ['es','SS']
```

This will be a dictionary which will contain a mapping for class and it's component names.The key will be class and it's values will be the names in that class, so a list of values for each class, where the list length might vary for each class.
Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be looking for a `groupby` + `to_dict` operation -

```
r = df.groupby('class').name.apply(list).to_dict()
```

Or,

```
r = df.groupby('class').name.agg(pd.Series.tolist).to_dict()
```

```
r
{'Base': ['es', 'SS'], 'Pref': ['Ab', 'Cw'], 'Val': ['BE']}
```

How it works -

- The `class` column consists of 3 categories. We want each category as an index.
- Furthermore, each element in the `name` column would need to be grouped by class and present in a list

It follows that a `groupby` operation is the most straightforward thing to do here. Group and apply/aggregate with `list` to get a series with index as so -

```
class
Base    [es, SS]
Pref    [Ab, Cw]
Val         [BE]
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Calling `to_dict` on this gives you what you want.